# How to plot a rootogram for a quasipoisson model?

Tags: r, plot, glm

I would like to plot a `rootogram` for a `quasipoisson` model. The countreg package works really well for poisson and for negative binomial but it says "family currently not supported" for quasipoisson models.

I know that the packages `vcd` and `latticeExtra` can also plot rootograms. Unfortunately, when I try to plot a `rootogram` of a `quasipoisson` model with these packages I receive error messages.

Here some code for all three packages:

```
#some data for replication)
y <- rpois(100, 3)
x1 <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50))
x2 <- rnorm(100, 1000, 300)
data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)

library(countreg)
countreg::rootogram(glm(y~x1 +x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson))
```

## produces error:

> Error in rootogram.glm(glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson)) : 
>     family currently not supported

```
library(vcd)
vcd::rootogram(glm(y~x1 + x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson))
```

## produces error:

> Error in rootogram.default(glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson)) : 
>     argument "fitted" is missing, with no default

```
library(latticeExtra)
latticeExtra::rootogram(glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson))
```

## produces error:

> Error in sqrt(as.vector(object)) : 
>     non-numeric argument to mathematical function

In addition: Warning message:

> In rootogram.default(glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson)) :
>     NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 1):

Not all libraries take a model object to plot results. Take a look at the documentation of these rootogram functions.

For instance, `vcd`'s function requires the data and predictions to make the plot. You can make the plot like so :

```
#some data for replication)
y <- rpois(100, 3)
x1 <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50))
x2 <- rnorm(100, 1000, 300)
data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)

mod <- glm(y~x1 +x2, data = data, family = quasipoisson)

library(vcd)
vcd::rootogram(data[,1], predict(mod), scale = "raw")
```

[image]

As a side note, I couldn't install `countreg` so I don't know what's wrong on that end.

Answer (score -1):

Try plotting a rootogram for the basic Poisson model with the same predictors. The predicted values and residuals are the same, so you can get a rough idea of the fit of your model.

On another note, @RoB, try install.packages("countreg", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")  to install the countreg package.